# Declaration in javascript

Tags: javascript

Greetnigs.

I'm new in javascript and I found something which is not familiar to me, yet. Could anyone tell me how it's properly called and how it works?

```
var EMPTY = 0, SNAKE = 1, FRUIT = 2;

var grid = 
{
    width: null,
    height: null,
    _grid: null,

    init: function(d, c, r)
    {

    },

    set: function(val, x, y)
    {

    },

    get: function(x, y)
    {

    }
}
```

First declaration is equal to 3 separated in different lines with var prefix?

Second one is an object with 3 properties and has declared 3 functions called: init, set and get, which will be extended later and those functions are available for this object?

Regards

Comment: It's just an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), called like `grid.set()`

Comment: In the object there's no function _declarations_, they are function expressions.

Comment: Yes. You can access it grid.get() , grid.set()

Comment: When did StackOverflow become an interactive tutorial?

Comment: @hege_hegedus - probably before it became douchebag meeting place. Since when people can't ask programming related questions here? You forgot that newcomers don't know the proper terminology or how to find information?

Comment: Thank you, your information was really helpful. As I can see, I was pretty close to truth. Adeneo's link has make everything clear. @hege_hegedus I hope I didn't insulted you, thanks for wasting your precious time on irrelevant case.